# Solution to $\Delta_g u = \delta-1$ on a 2-sphere.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $S^2$ be the two-sphere, endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$, such that the volume of the sphere w.r.t. this metric is $4\pi$. Let $a \in S^2$. I am looking for an easy way to prove that the equation
$$
\Delta_g u = 4 \pi \delta_a -1
$$
has a solution $u \in W^{1,p}$, $p \in (1,2)$.

This is an attempt I made: the weak formulation of this equation is
$$
-\int_{S^2} (\nabla \phi, \nabla u)_g d\mu_g = 4 \pi\phi(a) -\int_{S^2} \phi d\mu_g ,
$$
where integration is performed with respect to the measure induced by $g$, and $(\cdot, \cdot)_g$ is the inner product w.r.t. $g$.
We notice that the RHS of the previous equation is an element of $(W^{1,p})'$, for $p > 2$, by Sobolev embedding. I would then like to use some kind of  representation of $(W^{1,p})'$ to conclude that this functional can be represented as
$$
\int_{S^2} (\nabla \phi, \nabla u)_g d\mu_g
$$
for some $u$. Are there any ways to conclude? I guess this is pretty standard stuff, I would be very grateful if anyone could provide me a reference.

Comment: Just an idea: fix $p\in (1,2)$ and let $q=p/(p-1)$. Think of the Laplacian as the bounded operator $\Delta_g:W^{1,p}\to W^{-1,p}$ which corresponds to the bilinear form $a(f,g)=\int \nabla f\cdot \nabla g$ on $W^{1,p}\times W^{1,q}$. I think the image of $\Delta_g$ is precisely the subspace $N\subset W^{-1,p}$ that annihilates the constant function $1$, i.e., distributions with zero mean. Perhaps the [Banach space version of Lax-Milgram](http://n.ethz.ch/~giclaude/download/misc/laxmilgram.pdf) can be used, but it may be hard to verify its conditions.

Comment: @user75064: Let us solve an equation of the type $\Delta u = f$ in $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $B$ the open unit ball centered in $0$, where $f(v):= \int_{B} (y,y) \cdot \nabla v$. I think this particular $f$ lies in $N$ but not in the image of $\Delta$. What am I missing?

Comment: It's different on a ball, which has many nonconstant harmonic functions. The characterization of the range of Laplacian there is harder. On the sphere the only such functions are constants.